# Access/shortcut keys in East-Asian localized software?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, localization

I've been asked to produce a Japanese version of our desktop application, and possibly Chinese in the future. All strings are held in resource files, some of which include underscores for displaying access/shortcut keys, for example "_Save" or "Save _As...". When the `Alt` key is pressed an underscore appears (in Win7) beneath the relevant letter in the menu caption, button, or wherever.

Excuse my ignorance but given the written form of these languages, can access/shortcut keys still be used? i.e. is it still correct to place a shortcut key in front of a japanese character, as they aren't "letters" in the Western sense. If so, would a translator know where to place the underscores?

On a side-note does anyone still use access keys in desktop apps? The system all feels a bit 1990s now, and was wondering if I should even be bothering with it.

(It's a WPF application but I guess the question is still relevant to Winforms).

Comment: I suppose the answer to "does anyone still use access keys in desktop apps" depends on the target audience of the software. E.g. for programming IDEs and editors keyboard shortcuts are still used.
About where to place the underscores this image should give you an idea: https://revlog.work/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/japanize-10.jpg

Comment: @softbear my question relates to the underscores that are revealed when the 'Alt' key is pressed, rather than the shortcut names displayed on the R.H. side of menu items. I have now updated my question to make this clearer.

Comment: In the example image the shortcut key (when Alt key) are enclosed in brackets next to the actual menu item text.

Comment: @softbear my apologies. I was looking for underscores and didn't spot the letters in brackets. How was that achieved? When I did a quick test to localize my app to Japanese, I didn't see anything like that - just the underscored characters.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to a Chinese employee at our company, he confirmed that the underscoring would not make sense. The Chinese characters/symbols are not individual letters, so there would be no key on the keyboard to match the underlined character.